# Seaborn clustermap legend overlap with figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, legend

'''
Hi there,
I created a clustermap using seaborn. Because the legend overlaps with the figure, I'd like to move it. However, plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1,1)) gave the following error 'No handles with labels found to put in legend.'
That makes me wonder: what is the color scale -20 to 20 on the top left that I want to re-position? isn't that a legend?
Thank you in advance for shedding light on that for me.
'''

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

g = sns.clustermap(data=df_highestPivot,cmap='coolwarm')
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1,1)) #This line generate the error
plt.savefig('plot.png',dpi=300,bbox_to_inches='tight')
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

[image: clustermap with color legend overlapping with the figure]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The colorbar is not a *legend* per se (not an object of type `Legend` at least). It is actually it's own subplots Axes, that you can access using `g.ax_cbar`.

If you want to move it, you can pass an argument [`cbar_pos=` to `clustermap()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.clustermap.html). However, it's complicated to find an empty space in the figure to place it. I would recommend you make some room using `subplots_adjust()` then move the `ax_cbar` Axes at the desired location

```
iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
species = iris.pop("species")
g = sns.clustermap(iris)
g.fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.7)
g.ax_cbar.set_position((0.8, .2, .03, .4))
```

[image]